# print key and value javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, one with keys and the other with their values. I combined them into an object. I want to select few (not all) keys and their values from the object and print both - the key as well as its value. No jQuery or any other framework please. Here is my example:

```js
keys = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "ABC", "ZZZ"];
values = ["1", "2", "9", "DB", "xxx"];

var dict = {};
for (var x=0; x<keys.length; x++){
 dict[keys[x]] = values[x];
}

console.log(dict['EF']); //9
```

How do I get the output as EF:9

Comment: How are you planning to select the keys?

Comment: There are two questions: how to combine two arrays in a plain-object (`{AB: '1', CD: '2', ...}`), and how to select a certain value by key (`EF` → `9`). First is explained in comments, answer to the second is the last line in your code.

Comment: I know the key names to print - EF and ZZZ, for example

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin I know how to combine arrays into an object - already there in my code. I want to output both the key and its value, not just the value.

Comment: Yeah, but you already know the key, otherwise how would you do `dict['EF']` without knowing the "EF"? Either the question makes 0 sense, or you need to improve it so that everyone understands it, not just you alone.

Comment: `How do I get the output as EF:9` simply `console.log('EF:' + dict['EF'])` ... or `var key = 'EF'; console.log(key + dict[key])`

Comment: so, if there are many keys and their values to output, I will have to assign the key to a variable, print it, and then repeat for other keys?

Comment: `Object.keys(dict)` will gives you all the keys in an array

Comment: even if you wanna ignore stuff, you still gotta loop through it all to find the... nevermind, have you looked in to JSON at all? i promise it is a better way to locate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the key names and print them and the dict values.

```js
keys = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "ABC", "ZZZ"];
values = ["1", "2", "9", "DB", "xxx"];

var dict = {};
for (var x=0; x<keys.length; x++){
 dict[keys[x]] = values[x];
}

var keys_to_find = ['EF', 'ZZZ'];
keys_to_find.forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key + ":" + dict[key]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. That will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try `for` loop

```js
keys = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "ABC", "ZZZ"];
values = ["1", "2", "9", "DB", "xxx"];

var dict = {};
for (var x = 0; x < keys.length; x++) {
  dict[keys[x]] = values[x];
}

for (let i in dict) {
  console.log("key : " + i + " value : " + dict[i]);
}
```

Comment: I mentioned that I want only few keys - not all. Loop will not help. That part I already knew.

Comment: @ajay How will you select which keys to print?

Comment: I know the key names to print - EF and ZZZ, for example